# CDC debezium (postgres) is not publishing events for certain table

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I've set up a CDC pipeline in docker network using following scripts

1. zookeper

   ```
   --restart always \
   -p 2181:2181 \
   -p 2888:2888 \
   -p 3888:3888 \
   --network=test-net \
   -v /var/ibank/msdata/test/zookeper/config/zoo.cfg:/zookeper/conf/zoo.cfg \
   -v /var/ibank/msdata/test/zookeper/data/main-data:/zookeper/data \
   -v /var/ibank/msdata/test/zookeper/data/txns:/zookeper/txns \
   -v /var/ibank/msdata/test/zookeper/data/logs:/zookeper/logs \
   debezium/zookeeper:1.6
   ```
2. kafka

```
--name kafka \
--restart=always \
--network=test-net \
-p 9092:9092 \
-p 29092:29092 \
-e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka \
-e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT \
-e ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 \
-e KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092,PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092 \
-v /var/ibank/msdata/test/kafka/data/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data \
debezium/kafka:1.6
```

3. connect

```
--restart=always \
--net=test-net \
-p 8083:8083 \
-e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \
-e GROUP_ID=afr-group-test \
-e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=afr_storage_topic \
-e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=afr_offset_topic \
debezium/connect:1.6
```

4. added connector using the following config

```
{
    "name": "afr-connector",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
      "database.hostname": "postgres",
      "database.port": "5432",
      "database.user": "test_user",
      "database.password": "test_user",
      "database.dbname": "ibank",
      "database.server.name": "ibankserver1",
      "table.include.list": "private.sessions, private.transactions, private.failed_auth_attempts",
      "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
      "publication.autocreate.mode": "filtered",
      "snapshot.mode": "never",
      "heartbeat.interval.ms": 1000,
      "heartbeat.action.query": "update debezium_heartbeat set last_heartbeat_ts = now();"  
    }
  }
```

Postgres is in the same network, debezium connector successfully connects to the databse. PG user has all needed privileges (update, select, replication, login).

The problem is that I receive inerts (that's all I need) for transactions and failed_auth_attempts table but sessions table is not working.

What might be the problem?

here's a schema for the table

```
create table private.sessions
(
    id                        serial not null
        constraint sessions_pkey
            primary key,
    session_id                varchar(30),
    session_key               varchar(30),
    user_id                   integer
        constraint sessions_user_id_fkey
            references private.users,
    session_key_type          varchar(80),
    last_update_time          timestamp with time zone,
    ip_address                varchar,
    extradata                 jsonb,
    ip_address_location       varchar(30),
    auth_type                 varchar(30),
    user_agent_session_init   jsonb,
    last_used_ip_address      varchar(30),
    is_valid                  boolean,
    created_at                timestamp with time zone default now(),
    user_agent_session_actual jsonb,
    login_otp_sent_counter    integer                  default 0,
    otp_value                 varchar(8),
    restore_otp_sent_counter  integer                  default 0,
    firebase_token            varchar
);

alter table private.sessions
    owner to test_user;

grant select on private.sessions to test_user;

grant delete, insert, references, select, trigger, truncate, update on private.sessions to test_user;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out, debezium did not create publication only for "sessions" table for some unknown reason. Deleting the connector and recreating it did not help, then I manually deleted all publications that were created by debezium and recreated them for sessions table.

Comment: If publication exists but table is not linked to it, recreating publication can be avoided by executing query 
alter publication PUBLICATION add table TABLE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

You can set `skipped.operations=none` to [enable truncate events](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/documentation/modules/ROOT/pages/connectors/postgresql.adoc#postgresql-property-skipped-operations). The default value is "t" so it skips truncate operations.